# Uncaught TypeError: r.has is not a function

Tags: javascript, handsontable

The only change that i made is that I upgraded to the new version of handsontable; all other code is the same.  Working fine in v15.1, but v16.x or 17.0 both give me the error.  Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce in fsfiddle.  Even the most basic example is failing for me:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var container1 = document.getElementById('example1');
    var hot1;

    hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, {});
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<div id="example1"></div>
```

This should display a blank grid (and does in jsfiddle), but in my environment i get the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if you have the javascript file included, and make sure it is included *before* any calls to functions/entities contained in it.

Comment: Yes, including handsontable.full.min.js is the first thing that happens on the page.  Is there some other js file that is required?

Comment: And you've confirmed that it is included properly? (By that I mean check in your browser's Network tab (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I -> Network - may require a page reload) to see that no 404 errors are present). Besides that, I don't have any *handson* experience with this library, that was more a general troubleshooting comment.

Comment: Thanks TIm.  I can confirm that the library is being included.  In addition, it appears that the error message is coming from code in the included js file.

Comment: Hmm. Only other thing I can think of is `container1` is not what you think it is, or some functionality of the constructor has changed between the 2 versions. Example, if `container1` came back null, you'd get the console error `TypeError: rootElement is null`. If it came back as a string or int (ie not an object), you would get `TypeError: rootElement is undefined`. So you can see how you can get errors from the included js file. This being said, without a working example of the exact problem, I can only speculate what is triggering that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what environment you are working in, but I was able to identify the reason for this error in VisualForce.

The same problem happened: handsontable was upgraded from version 15 to version 20 and the page stopped working with similar error:

```
TypeError: samples.has is not a function.
```

Variable samples is initialized in handsontable.full.js as: var samples = new Map(); and the variable Map was getting overwritten by Salesforce main.js.

I've replaced Map with hotMap through out handsontable.full.js and page is working now.

It looks like you have the conflict with variables from different included js files in your environment too.

Not good that I had to change handsontable.full.js of course but could not think of anything else.

Comment: Thank you, error is not in Handsontable, but as you wrote, in own defined Map function somewhere else.